# Изменение ссылки внутри iframe, загруженном с другого сайта

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Как изменить статичную ссылку в `iframe`, загруженном с другого сайта?

```html
<iframe src="адрес сайта" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; overflow:visible; width:100%; height:100%;" 
        allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

**Обновление**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href='favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<iframe src="адрес сайта" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:visible; width:100%; height:100%;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Можете показать код, который вы использовали что бы это сделать?

Comment: @Melinio Saidolim Djuraev имел в виду не тот код, который надо менять, а тот, которым. Вы же пишете программу, которая будет менять ссылку, так? Вот, покажите, что уже есть. А то непонятно даже, какой язык.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я знаю, это невозможно, поскольку нельзя работать с DOM-элементом, загруженным с другого домена, из-за политики безопасности.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий вариант. Но вас сайт имеет блокировку на замену ссылок. Так что там еще есть дела поважнее.

```js
function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
  var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
  if ($iframe.length) {
    $('#' + iframeName + ' a[href$="http://filmix.net/mynews"]').attr('href', url);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="http://moinovosti.ru" onclick="return loadIframe('ifrm', this.href);">Новости</a>

    </li>

  </ul>
  <iframe src="http://filmix.net" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:visible; width:100%; height:100%;" id="ifrm" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Мне надо что бы например в iframe загружался "www.yandex.ru" и вместо ссылки "карты" https://maps.yandex.ru/ была моя ссылка сразу после загрузки iframe.

Comment: получается у вас не ссылка `iframe` меняется а ссылка внутри `iframe` а меняется. Тогда постановка задачи меняется, поменяйте задачу и дайте конкретный пример, в каком сайте какую ссылку нужно поментять

Comment: Вот сайт: http://filmix.net/ на нем надо поменять ссылку "Новости" http://filmix.net/mynews

Comment: Надо так что бы "налету" менялась ссылка, без нажатия на отдельную ссылку.

Comment: на лету  можете сделать сами уже. создайте событие и пожалуйста

Comment: К сожалению у меня нету знаний в данной области. Вы не могли бы отредактировать свой вариант данный выше с событием?

Comment: Я сейчас попробовал ваш вариант и не понимаю в чем смысл? Вверху ссылка моя, внутри фрейма остается стандартная ссылка, при нажатии на ссылку внутри фрейма открывается ссылка которая указана на офф источнике а не моя. Возможно вы меня не правильно поняли?